# How should I access the JSON Array having a numeric key?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "2": [{
        "name": "Jeevan",
        "age": "7"
    },
    {
        "name": "Jeet",
        "age": "8"
    }],
    "school": "Kendriya Vidyalaya"
}
```

I am having this JSON stored in variable named Obj. I would like to access individual JSON Objects inside of JSON Array which has a a key as "2".
Please help me to access the same.

As far as conventional way is considered i.e
   Obj.key, it is not applicable here because Obj.2 or Obj."2" is not allowed.

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are working with javascript.

Try to access the date like this:

```
array = Obj["2"]
```

Comment: Thanks For Your Help!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var o = { "2": [{ "name": "Jeevan", "age": "7" }, { "name": "Jeet", "age": "8" } ], "school": "Kendriya Vidyalaya" };
o["2"];
o["school"]
```

Comment: I am grateful to you !!